Bug: Does adding a link mess up the link numbers?
I think I found a severe bug while trying to edit an answer, and I'm unsure where to report it.
So I'm doing it just here:
An answer that had about 15 links was edited to make some word in the middle (after the first link and before the last link) a link.
However, contrary to expectations, the new link was not numbered "N+1" (N being the highest link number used), but got some number in between, say "13".
If I hadn't noticed this before saving, my edit would have messed up most of the links.

I was wrong!
The system is more clever than I had expected:
Consider this example:
Before editing there was a link like this:
The asnwer is from [draft-irtf-cfrg-argon2-03][11];

...
  [11]: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-argon2-03#page-13
...

After inserting a new link (that became #13) elsewehere, the text had been changed to:
The asnwer is from [draft-irtf-cfrg-argon2-03][8];

...
  [8]: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-argon2-03#page-13
...


Yeah, it is able to perform a basic renumbering (I hope some of you get the joke). Note that generic issues with the [se] system are better re-searched / asked on [meta.se], as this is not a [crypto.se] specific topic.

Yep, this is something I love about how the link formatting works in the current network-wide editor. :)
